# How to parse this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> The figures will likely strengthen concern among economists already
>   worried about how Japan's domestic-driven recovery will fare once the
>   nation's sales tax is raised to 8% from 5% in April.

I parse the sentence like this:

> The figures / will likely strengthen / concern / among economists/ (who/ are)
>   already / worried/ about (how /Japan's domestic-driven recovery /will
>   fare / once / the nation's sales tax / is raised / to 8% from 5% / in
>   April). Economists / expect / at least a temporary chill / in demand
>   (when / the new rate / goes into effect.)

I wonder whether the way I parse the sentence is right.

Answer (score 2):

the beginning of sentence "The figures will likely strengthen" seem to have a problem. You can edit it to "The figures will **most** likely strengthen" or "The figures will **probably** strengthen"

The figures / will **most** likely/ strengthen concern / among economists/ (who are)/ already worried about/ (how /Japan's domestic-driven recovery /will fare / once the nation's sales tax / is raised / to 8% from 5% / in April)./ Economists expect / at least /a temporary chill / in demand /(when / the new rate / goes into effect.)

whatever in parenthesis should begin separately and end separately (as marked) , when that is done the next step would be to see where you want to stress. you can stress at the concern, economists, worried, Japan's ... ,to 8%,  new rate.

Think about what is important , stress them, parse it and then try reading it. The final version comes when you try speaking and getting the message to be conveyed.

Comment: I don't see a problem with 'likely strengthen'. Adding 'most' just increases the likelihood.